# Minecraft Multiplayer Server Coordinates Export?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I play Minecraft on a big multiplayer server, and via voting, I lucked into a higher rank that lets me set unlimited homes. I loving being able to TP anywhere so I've set maybe 60-70 so far.

Here's the thing. I'd love to be able to map the coordinates of these homes, just to see a visual layout of where I've been, and where I can travel to. But for that, I'd need a full list of the X,Y,Z coordinates at each of my homes. I haven't been writing them down, but theoretically I could tp back to each one and manually record it's coordinates. Of course, this would take a really, really long time and would generally be a headache.

So tl;dr: Is there anyway for me to export the coordinates of my personal homes from a multiplayer server? I'm not looking for anyone else's info here or to cheat or hack or anything, I just want a simple clean list of all the coordinates I personally have /sethome.

This maybe/probably is impossible, but I thought I'd ask. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

## This answer assumes that your server is using [Essentials](https://hub.spigotmc.org/jenkins/job/spigot-essentials/) and its `/home` command.

Unfortunately, there is **no way** you can display your homes in-game. Not even with the `/home` command without arguments (that lists just the names all your homes). As you said, the only way to 'export' them to teleport to them all and write the coordinates down.

However, if you *do* have access to the server's files, you can find them in your user data folder under `<Server Directory>/plugins/Essentials/userdata/<Your UUID or username in offline mode>.yml` in the following format:

```
homes:
  <name you use in /home [name]>:
    world: <world name>
    x: <x coord>
    y: <y coord>
    z: <z coord>
    yaw: <yaw>
    pitch: <pitch>
```

As for a client-side script, that does that: I do not know of any.